# BigQuery Update a Repeated column in a Table using another table

Tags: google-bigquery, sql-update, sql-merge

I am trying to write an update or merge BigQuery SQL to update the data_profile.name  of  table1 (repeated column) using another reference table having dataprofile data of table2 (flattendata).

[image]

Using SQL:

```
UPDATE `dataset.table_1`
SET data_profiles = ARRAY(
  SELECT (
    adp.id,dp.name
    )
     FROM UNNEST(data_profiles) AS adp join `dataset.table_2` dp on adp.id =dp.id 
)
WHERE true
```

but we want to update only the data_profile.name which got updated in SOURCE TABLE to avoid updation on all columns.

Please suggest any merge or update statement for this scenario.

Comment: There's some column in source table to identify if the name got updated?

Comment: @damiao Martins -Yes, the reference table that we are going to use would be the delta table only instead of the main reference table ,so we can consider the Source table would have only delta records .

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to update an array_agg struct with an array, try something like this:

```
UPDATE `dataset.table_1` t1
SET t1.data_profiles  = (
   SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(t2.id, t2.name))
   FROM `dataset.table_2` t2
   WHERE t2.id = t1.id
   GROUP BY t2.id
)
WHERE true
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `source` table have only delta changes and `target` table have an unique row identifier (e.g. `col1`), you can do a MERGE like this:

```sql
MERGE `lab.target_table` T
USING (
  SELECT 
    t.col1,
    ARRAY_AGG(
        STRUCT(
          adp.id,
          COALESCE(dp.name, adp.name) as name
        )
    ) as data_profiles
  FROM `lab.target_table` t, UNNEST(t.data_profiles) AS adp 
    LEFT JOIN `lab.source_table` dp on adp.id = dp.id 
  WHERE 
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM UNNEST(t.data_profiles) AS adp join `lab.source_table` dp on adp.id = dp.id)
  GROUP BY col1
) S
ON T.col1 = S.col1
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET data_profiles = S.data_profiles, dt = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```

That way only rows in `target` table that contains data_profiles in the `source` table will be updated.