# Updating bigquery nested record with repeated mode

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigdata, schema, sqldatatypes

`UPDATE` dataset_a.table_a`AS n SET nested_record_datatype_column_with_repeated_mode = ARRAY( SELECT AS STRUCT col2, '', '', '', col5, '' FROM`dataset_b.table_B`tm WHERE tm.common_column_to_join = n.common_column_to_join ) WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM`dataset_c.table_c `AS dm WHERE n.common_column_to_join = dm.common_column_to_join )`

dataset_a.table_a have column with record dataype with repeated mode - nested_record_datatype_column_with_repeated_mode.

I am trying to update the values of bigquery table which has record dataype with repeated mode.
I want to select the Column values from another table and update those values into that nested column.
I have searched everywhere but could not find any solution which is working.

I tried using select as sturct. But that gave an error -
Value of type ARRAY<STRUCT<business_name STRING, addr_line_1 STRING, STRING, ...>> cannot be assigned to golden_account_records, which has type ARRAY<STRUCT<business_name STRING, addr_line_1 STRING, addr_line_2 STRING, ...>>

I have verified all the columns and their datatypes if they are matching with source and destination tables and everything is correct.

Comment: Repeated is an array, you need to unnest it. Share you code if you want more help

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77194184/bigquery-update-a-repeated-column-in-a-table-using-another-table/77207478

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Updated the code and description. Please help if you could find anything.

Comment: @DamiãoMartins Tried the solution provided, but its not working. It is giving me an error mentioned in the problem statement above.

Comment: name your '' field with a AS.